# How do I create an array from a single form input box with php on octobercms?

Tags: php, arrays, forms, laravel, octobercms

I have a input box called 'str_local_og_fb_admins' and I want that input box to be able to have more than one admin, like if I input in the form "1234,5678" I want the return to be:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="1234">
<meta property="fb:admins" content="5678">
```

I'm able to create one tag only like if I put this in my form "1234,5678" it returns:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="1234,5678">
```

I'm working at a octobercms plugin to handle open graph tags and that is the only problem I'm having, here is the input field I created(it's created at the plugin.php file):

```
if (!$widget->model instanceof \Cms\Classes\Page) return;

    $widget->addFields([
    'settings[str_local_og_fb_admins]' => [
                            'label' => 'Facebook Admins',
                            'type'  => 'text',
                            'placeholder' => 'Example: 1234',
                            'tab'   => 'Facebook Tags',
                          ]],  'primary');
```

I output the tags using a component I have created, this is how my default.htm of that component looks like:

```
{% if this.page.str_local_og_fb_admins %}
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="{{this.page.str_local_og_fb_admins}}">
{% endif %}
```

I also set in the database the field as string.
(My plugin is a backend plugin, all my forms only appear in the backend pages)

Comment: the question looks like a mess to me... can you please edit it, so it would be clear what do you want and what is the input data? I read three times, and still don't understand where's the issue and what you need to achieve.

Comment: I have one form field and if I input there "123,321" it gives me the value "123,321" but I want it to give me 
123 and 321 separately, basicly I want to split a string into an array

Comment: find the answer on your comment in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37280068/4354249)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have one form field and if I input there "123,321" it gives me the
>   value "123,321" but I want it to give me 123 and 321 separately,
>   basicly I want to split a string into an array

The answer is trivial, use [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function in PHP for this:

```
$str = "123,321";
$pieces = explode(",", $str);
echo $pieces[0]; // "123"
echo $pieces[1]; // "321"
```

Comment: Thank you I had to make some minor changes to the code so it works but you helped a lot.

Comment: @kraven2g was it the answer on your question, or you asked something else? feel free [to accept an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it was exactly what you was asking for, because original question was kind of confusing.

Comment: it isn't 100% of what I needed but let's say that your answer was solved about 70% of my problem, my code is now working 100% thanks.

Comment: haha, @kraven2g, you are so precise in percentages... anyways, good you have the solution. It sounds to me **the question is resolved** anyways.